# Has anyone gotten host-proof web application architecture completely right yet?

Tags: architecture, cryptography, security

Aldo Cortesi wrote an excellent review of host-proof architecture in this blog post, though Feb 2010 is a bit outdated now:

http://corte.si/posts/security/hostproof.html

Have there been any notable developments in this area since?  I don't see any later articles on Cortesi's blog, or any on the Wikipedia page that add significantly more to Cortesi's article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_Proof_Storage

I'm particularly interested in whether anyone has solved the checksum problem.  You can deliver all the client code as a single blob, then provide a checksum for it for the client user to verify, but the checksum has to come from a trusted third party, not the application host you don't trust in the first place.  Anyone doing that or anything like it?

Comment: It seems tarsnap does this.  The "checksum problem" isn't a problem, because all you have to do is upload an authentication code with the data, the server sends the data back with the authentication code.  When data is encrypted, it almost *always* has an authentication code in it anyway.  In this basic system, the worst a host can do is roll back data or delete it, and you can mitigate that by requiring the host to provide an authenticated manifest.

Comment: @ByronGibson: I voting this as off-topic. stackoverflow is for programming questions, [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) is I think the right place for this question. NOTE: I personally think breaking up stackoverflow into so many little websites is a mistake but that is what the owners want.

Comment: Makes more sense on security.SE than on webmasters.

Comment: @GregS: No problem, I asked this almost three years ago anyway, and several such frameworks have been developed since, added below.  And agreed it would have been better to keep all programming-related ones combined and used tags and other internal systems to organize it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question almost three years ago, some promising projects have been released:

1. SpiderOak's [Crypton.io](https://crypton.io/)
2. Stanford's [Hails](http://hails.scs.stanford.edu/)
3. MIT's [Mylar](http://css.csail.mit.edu/mylar/)